# Angular 7 CRUD App Service not connecting to REST Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, angular7

I'm trying to build an Angular 7 CRUD app with a REST Api following [this tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5bca67d780aca7466989441f/angular-7-tutorial-building-crud-web-application#ch4).

Simply put it's a classic display products , add , edit and all that jazz kinda app.

The Rest API is made using Mongoose, Express and Node. Both the Angular App and the server are running fine on their own.

When I use mongod in the cmd it's waiting for an answer , and with the npm start in the api it does connect successfully.

Everything about the App works too without compilation errors.

But the app doesn't seem to be connected to the api at all , when I try to add a product to the empty list it just keeps on loading without going any further.

This is the service typescript file that I have :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from './products';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
const apiUrl = "/api/v1/products";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(apiUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => console.log('fetched products')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getProducts', []))
      );
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Product>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched product id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Product>(`getProduct id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  addProduct(product): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.post<Product>(apiUrl, product, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((product: Product) => console.log(`added product w/ id=${product._id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Product>('addProduct'))
    );
  }
  updateProduct(id, product): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, product, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`updated product id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateProduct'))
    );
  }

  deleteProduct(id): Observable<Product> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<Product>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`deleted product id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Product>('deleteProduct'))
    );
  }
}
```

This is the app.js file for the api:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var restful = require('node-restful');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cors = require('cors');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var products = require('./routes/products');
var app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/product')
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cors());
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/api/v1/products', products);

var Category = app.resource = restful.model('category', mongoose.Schema({
  cat_name: String,
}))
.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

Category.register(app, '/category');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json(err.message);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I don't have any error report to share at the moment, if you need more from the code I'll provide it as soon as I can.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : The product-add component where I call the service :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-add',
  templateUrl: './product-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-add.component.css']
})
export class ProductAddComponent implements OnInit {

  productForm: FormGroup;
  prod_name: string = '';
  prod_desc: string = '';
  prod_price: number = null;
  updated_at: Date = null;
  isLoadingResults = false;

  onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.api.addProduct(form)
      .subscribe(res => {
        let id = res['_id'];
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/product-details', id]);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private api: ApiService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'prod_name': [null, Validators.required],
      'prod_desc': [null, Validators.required],
      'prod_price': [null, Validators.required],
      'updated_at': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

EDIT 2 : Some error logs that I didn't find at first , when accessing the app and it's trying to display a list from the server :

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/products 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:407
onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @   zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone    @   zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @   zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function)  @   zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @   http.js:1630
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:29
(anonymous) @   subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult   @   subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub  @   mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext   @   mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next  @   mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @   scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @   mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @   filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call   @   map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call    @   tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call  @   catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../src/app/products/products.component.ts.ProductsComponent.ngOnInit    @   products.component.ts:20
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline   @   core.js:18668
checkAndUpdateNodeInline    @   core.js:19932
checkAndUpdateNode  @   core.js:19894
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @   core.js:20528
debugCheckDirectivesFn  @   core.js:20488
(anonymous) @   ProductsComponent_Ho…gfactory.js? [sm]:1
debugUpdateDirectives   @   core.js:20480
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:19876
callViewAction  @   core.js:20117
execEmbeddedViewsAction @   core.js:20080
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:19877
callViewAction  @   core.js:20117
execComponentViewsAction    @   core.js:20059
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:19882
callWithDebugContext    @   core.js:20770
debugCheckAndUpdateView @   core.js:20448
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges  @   core.js:18257
(anonymous) @   core.js:14919
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @   core.js:14919
(anonymous) @   core.js:14810
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:388
onInvoke    @   core.js:14191
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run   @   zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run  @   core.js:14105
next    @   core.js:14810
schedulerFn @   core.js:10206
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub   @   Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next  @   Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @   Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit   @   core.js:10190
checkStable @   core.js:14160
onHasTask   @   core.js:14204
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask   @   zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount  @   zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount  @   zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask   @   zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @   zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)        
scheduleMicroTask   @   zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @   zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @   zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then   @   zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @   core.js:14691
./src/main.ts   @   main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:78
0   @   main.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules    @   bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @   main.js:1
api.service.ts:22 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/v1/products", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/v1/products</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/v1/products: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/v1/products"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Also the one I get when I try to add a new product :

```
zone.js:2969 POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/products 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @ http.js:1630
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../src/app/product-add/product-add.component.ts.ProductAddComponent.onFormSubmit @ product-add.component.ts:23
(anonymous) @ ProductAddComponent.html:10
handleEvent @ core.js:19676
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:20770
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:20473
dispatchEvent @ core.js:17125
(anonymous) @ core.js:18615
schedulerFn @ core.js:10218
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:10190
push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.onSubmit @ forms.js:4647
(anonymous) @ ProductAddComponent.html:10
handleEvent @ core.js:19676
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:20770
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:20473
dispatchEvent @ core.js:17125
(anonymous) @ core.js:17572
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:993
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14182
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
api.service.ts:22 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/v1/products", ok: false, …}
(anonymous) @ api.service.ts:22
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error @ catchError.js:34
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error @ tap.js:61
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError @ OuterSubscriber.js:13
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error @ InnerSubscriber.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
onLoad @ http.js:1547
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14182
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
(anonymous) @ http.js:1619
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../src/app/product-add/product-add.component.ts.ProductAddComponent.onFormSubmit @ product-add.component.ts:23
(anonymous) @ ProductAddComponent.html:10
handleEvent @ core.js:19676
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:20770
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:20473
dispatchEvent @ core.js:17125
(anonymous) @ core.js:18615
schedulerFn @ core.js:10218
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:10190
push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.onSubmit @ forms.js:4647
(anonymous) @ ProductAddComponent.html:10
handleEvent @ core.js:19676
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:20770
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:20473
dispatchEvent @ core.js:17125
(anonymous) @ core.js:17572
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:993
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14182
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
core.js:12632 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (product-add.component.ts:24)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyNext (OuterSubscriber.js:10)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at subscribeTo.js:16
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
```

And the products.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Product = require('../models/Product.js');

/* GET ALL PRODUCTS */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
  });
});

/* GET SINGLE PRODUCT BY ID */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* SAVE PRODUCT */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* UPDATE PRODUCT */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* DELETE PRODUCT */
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to call that Angular service please?

Comment: Just did , is that what you meant ?

Comment: If you use something like Postman directly against the API, are you seeing the proper responses? Also in the network or console tabs you do not see any errors on the client side? What does `products.js` in your Express app look like?

Comment: I got some errors , it looks like it's not the proper routing to access the api or something alone those lines , I'm going to paste them here and also the products.js that you are asking for

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is not complete. The author was missing a very essential part: because we are in a development environment, usually our RESTful server and a client application running under localhost, but on different ports. To get it to communicate with each other, we need a simple proxy:

Create the proxy.conf.json in root (src) folder and insert the following code:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Replace "/api/*" and RESTful server port# with yours ":3000" and when starting Angular client, use this command:

ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

(For RESTful server: npm run start)

### After applying these changes, the tutorial works ~ 90%!

DELETE API is not working and if I am not wrong, the request was not blocked by CORS, because in our case we already using a proxy. The API is working fine because, with Postman, I can delete the article. See the console error below:

```
zone-evergreen.js:2952 DELETE http://localhost:4200/api/article/5d336729fafe194efa7fb102 500 (Internal Server Error)
api.service.ts:20 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/article/5d336729fafe194efa7fb102", ok: false, …}
```